# Resend request angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs5, angular2-http

In angular 2 app every request to API has header with token, in case token has expired API responds with 401 http code. I have a method to update token, but how I can resend previous request pausing others while a new token is in the process of getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the `Http` class for this this way, catch the error using the `catch` operator of observables:

An approach could be to extend the HTTP object to intercept errors:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

and register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

Within the callback defined in the `catch` operator, you could call your method to update the token, get the result, set the new token on the source request and execute it again. This would be completely transparent.

Here is a sample:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        return this.getToken().flatMap(token => {
          var sourceOptions = options || {};
          var headers = sourceOptions.headers || new Headers();
          headers.append('Authorization', token); // for example
          return super.get(url, options);
        });
      }

      return Observable.throw(res);
    });
  }
```

**Edit**

To "pause" other requests you need to implement some caching within the `getToken` method using the `do` and `share` operators:

```
getToken() {
  if (hasTokenExpired()) {
    this.token = null;
    this.tokenObservable = null;
  }

  if (this.token) {
    // Gotten the new token
    return Observable.of(this.token);
  } else if (this.tokenObservable) {
    // Request in progress...
    return this.tokenObservable;
  } else {
    // Execute the "refresh token" request
    return this.get('/refreshToken')
      .map(res => res.json)
      .do(token => {
        this.token = token;
        this.tokenObservable = null;
      })
      .share();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how I can pause other requests while I am getting a new token?

Comment: You're welcome! I would implement some caching in the `getToken` method. I udpated my answer accordingly...

Comment: which version of rxjs u used in examples?