# $http.defaults.headers in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

I'm using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for authorization. In AngularJS 1.x I used the following function to login:

```
    function login(username, password) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post("/api/login", {
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        }).then(function(response) {
            if (response.data && response.data.token) {
                var tokenBegin = response.data.token.substring(0,6);
                var bearer = (tokenBegin === 'Bearer') ? '' : 'Bearer ';
                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = bearer + response.data.token;
                deferred.resolve({ status: true, message: 'Login complete' });
            } else {
                deferred.reject(response);
            }
        }, function(reason) {
            deferred.reject(reason)
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

that is amending the `$http.defaults` object. I'm a little at loss in Angular2 and TypeScript since the Http class doesn't seem to have a `defaults` object. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

- You can implement your own `BaseRequestOptions` class:

  ```
  import {BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs} from '@angular/http';

  export class AppRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor() {
    }

    merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
      options.url = 'https://www.test.org' + options.url;
      return super.merge(options);
    }
  }
  ```

  and I register it this way:

  ```
  bootstrap(App, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: AppRequestOptions})
  ]);
  ```
- Extend the `Http` (or `XHRBackend`) class itself:

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class CustomHttp extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
      super(backend, defaultOptions);
    }

    request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      console.log('request...');
      return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
        // do something
      });        
    }

    get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      console.log('get...');
      return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
        // do something
      });
    }
  }
  ```

  and register it as described below:

  ```
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    })
  ]);
  ```

See these questions:

- [Dependency injection does not load all params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124321/dependency-injection-does-not-load-all-params/38124520#38124520)
- [Angular2 RC BaseRequestOption Constructor Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549599/angular2-rc-baserequestoption-constructor-injection/37549934#37549934)
- [Resend request angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306671/resend-request-angular-2/37307639#37307639)

Comment: I presume like this: `merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
    options.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer: sometoken';
    return super.merge(options);
  }`